# How do I draw this BST tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

Confused about the BST tree drawing, say you want to insert the values 12, 9, 4, 6, 5, 15, 14, 16, 17, 18 into an empty binary search tree in the given order without balancing.
What will the tree be like after each insertion?
And what will happen to the tree if the value 12 is deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### BST Tree Drawing

[image]

---

### Tree: Value 12 is deleted

[image]

---

Comment: In the situation of the first question, add the vertices to an empty AVL tree with balancing. (If you use a rotation include details in your description.) What will the drawing be like then? Thanks!!

Comment: @dffd You asked the question for BST Tree which I have answered. Please ask a different question for the AVL tree. If you found my answer useful, please accept that.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that. Could you maybe elaborate a little on the steps?